# Setting up Visual Studio windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, development-environment

I've set up Visual Studio 2008, exactly as I want it with one screen (got dual monitors) used only for coding and the other setup with multiple tab groups, each containing different tabs, like one group contains the output, error list and todo list tabs, another group has tabs for the toolbox and properties windows.

Now this is all cool and everything, except when if I debug something and I'm done debugging it throws all the tabs together into one group and screws up all my nicely separate tab groups.

Anyone know of anything that will stop Visual Studio from doing this and remember which tabs goes into what groups?

Answer (score 14):

This is because VS has separate layout settings for coding and debugging.  The idea being that when coding you don't want things like the output window etc, you want solution explorer and a nice large code window.  When debugging, you still want to see code, but also possibly lots of other windows to help you (threads, breakpoints etc).

In fact I believe there are lots of window layouts available (in additional to your own customisation).  This is one of the things Visual Studio asks you when you first start it up and are setting up your environment.

The only way I know to resolve this is to also re-arrange your windows "while" debugging.  It should remember those settings and switch to them when you are debugging.

Comment: Johan, don't forget to mark this as the answer if you feel it solved your problem.